# Microsoft Exchange Web Services make sure email sent successfully

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is there a way to make sure that email that I am sending via Microsoft Exchange Web Services is sent successfully? This is the code I am using:

```
        var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
        {
            Credentials = new WebCredentials(EmailFrom, Password),
            Url = new Uri(ExchangeUrl),
        };

        var email = new EmailMessage(service)
        {
            Subject = "Test",
            Body = "Hello from .net!",
        };

        email.ToRecipients.Add(EmailTo);

        email.Send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sends are Asynchronous in EWS so all you will get back is the status of the submission when you run Send. Because your not even saving the Sent Message to the SentItem folder probably the only way would be to set the Internet MessageId before you send then track the Message in the Tracking Logs on the server

```
    ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidTagInternetMessageId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(4149, MapiPropertyType.String);
    EmailMessage ema = new EmailMessage(service);
    ema.Subject ="test from ews";
    ema.Body = new MessageBody("test<br>Rgds<>");
    ema.ToRecipients.Add("gscales@domain.com");
    ema.SetExtendedProperty(PidTagInternetMessageId,("<" +Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "@domain.com>"));
    ema.Send();
```

Comment: What if I save it using SendAndSaveCopy? Will I be able to see if the message was delivered from the same client app?

Comment: You will see if its been Sent, For Delivery you need to use Tracking logs or delivery notification or something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/track-messages-with-delivery-reports?view=exchserver-2019